# How to generate sugared assembly code from Solidity code?

Tags: solc, assembly

In the [Solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/assembly.html) I see a sample assembly code:

```
{
  mstore(0x40, 0x60) // store the "free memory pointer"
  // function dispatcher
  switch div(calldataload(0), exp(2, 226))
  case 0xb3de648b {
    let (r) = f(calldataload(4))
    let ret := $allocate(0x20)
    mstore(ret, r)
    return(ret, 0x20)
  }
  default { revert(0, 0) }
  // memory allocator
  function $allocate(size) -> pos {
    pos := mload(0x40)
    mstore(0x40, add(pos, size))
  }
  // the contract function
  function f(x) -> y {
    y := 1
    for { let i := 0 } lt(i, x) { i := add(i, 1) } {
      y := mul(2, y)
    }
  }
}
```

that's generated from this Solidity code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract C {
  function f(uint x) returns (uint y) {
    y = 1;
    for (uint i = 0; i < x; i++)
      y = 2 * y;
  }
}
```

How can I generate the same assembly code with solc?

I know I can use `--asm` option but it produces desugared code.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/1472) GitHub the following question was asked regarding the status of standalone assembly:

> Is this already implemented? It shows up in the documentation but I
>   can see no other evidence of it being implemented:
>   http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/assembly.html?highlight=assembly#standalone-assembly

Response to this by the contributor was

> No, this is still work in progress. There is a note about it in the
>   documentation, but not too visible, I have to admit.

This is the only evidence that I have got which is related to the above issue.