# Is there any way to debug a smart contract bytecode by Remix?

Tags: remix

I'm looking for a way to avoid using 3-rd party tools to debug smartcontract without source code. Can I do it by Remix?

I think this way: we need some tool to convert a bytecode or assembly of contract functions to inline assembly (function-style would be ideally) that supported by solc and then I can just copy-paste it to Remix.

Also [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29774/how-to-generate-sugared-assembly-code-from-solidity-code?rq=1) question is relevant, but still without an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the answer is you cannot do this with Remix because this is not available with Remix as of now.